# emit checkbox control modelValue back to parent control vue3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have a wrapper control for checkboxes, very similar to my textbox control.
Doing it this way validation and design will always be consistent. I got this to work for textboxes, but the boolean value for checked is causing complications.

[Two way binding of data between child and parent using emit vue3 typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71215080/two-way-binding-of-data-between-child-and-parent-using-emit-vue3-typescript)

```
<template>
  <label class="checkCtrl">
    <input
      role="checkbox"
      aria-disabled="false"
      aria-readonly="false"
      type="checkbox"
      v-model="checked"
      v-on:change="change($event)"
    />
    <span><LocCtrl :page="page" :loc-key="labelLoc" /></span>
  </label>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useModelWrapper } from "../utils/modelWrapper";
import LocCtrl from "../components/LocCtrl.vue";
import Locale from "@/services/Locale";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "CheckCtrl",
  components: {
    LocCtrl,
  },
  props: {
    labelLoc: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    page: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {

    const value = useModelWrapper(props, emit, "value");
    return {
      value: value,
      checked: value.value == "true"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getLoc(locKey: string): string {
      return Locale.getItem(this.page, locKey);
    },
    change(e: Event): void {
      if (e) {
        this.value = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).checked ? "true" : "false";
        this.$emit('update:modelValue',  this.value);
        alert(this.value);
      }
    }
  },
});
</script>
```

This is the model wrapper, which worked for textbox, but isn't for this

```
import { computed } from "vue";
export function useModelWrapper(
  props: { [x: string]: any },
  emit: (arg0: string, arg1: any) => void,
  name = "modelValue"
) {
  return computed({
    get: () => {
      return props[name];
    },
    set: (value: string) => {
      return emit("update:" + name, value)
    }
  });
}
```

In the parent I am passing the v-model to the control. Strings "true" or "false" are the expected values (I will probably make this configurable if we need it).

```
<FormLine className="forCheck" form-line="3">
    <CheckCtrl v-model="claim.resultOfAccident" labelLoc="RoA" page="claims3View"/>
</FormLine>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, yet again I found an answer to my own problem, but I hope it helps someone else:

```
change(e: Event): void {
   if (e) {
      const value = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).checked ? "true" : "false";
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', value);
   }
}
```

this.value wasn't correct in the original code.